# Hide chrome selenium browser by window handle

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was able to hide the process(selenium chrome browser) by using FindWindow and the lpWindowname by changing the document.title with Javascript to a specific Window Name in order to hide the process. But I want to be able to hide the process(selenium chrome browser) by a different handle since my program navigates through different websites, therefore, changing the window name each time.

Here is my code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (on)
        {

            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Window Name - Google Chrome");
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // Hide the window
            }

            button1.Text = "Show";
            t.Start();
            on = false;

        }
        else {

            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Window Name - Google Chrome");
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); //Show Window

            }

            button1.Text = "Hide";
            t.Stop();
            on = true;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain you scenario a little better. Why do you need to find that window handle every time?  Once you have it, keep it and use it. Unless you are trying to monitor it, so it might close. But then I don't get how Javascript fits in all this. However, you can also use `Process.GetProcessesByName()`, so you don't have to care about the window title.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, I will edit the post once more. Basically, the program will be navigating through websites, therefore, changing the Window Title. I was using javascript to change the document.title to a specific window name to be able to hide it. I hope that clears up the confusion.